# How to key.tab and sendkeys through a form of input fields without element locators?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to fill out a form page with many types of input fields(text, radiobuttons, number fields, etc.) but the problem is all the fields are dynamic which makes it difficult to work with.

I was wondering if its possible to just key.tab through each fields and send.keys without specifying the element of the fields? or would I need to somehow find a way to use parent div and drill them down until I find the specific element. Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have so far in my selenium C# script:

```
        public void FillOutForm()
    {
        //this fills out the first text input field: correct
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id,'sa-txt')]")).SendKeys("Timmy");

        //tab to next input field
        builder.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();

        //this actually enters the text on another field in the form and not the second field: incorrect
        new Actions(Driver).SendKeys("Jones").Perform();

        builder.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();

        Utils.Pause(5000);
    }
```

Also a screenshot of the UI inspect [ImageofUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJhRp.png)

Comment: Hi Rehan, have you tried using a CSS selector with [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)?

Comment: I have not, I will do some googling to figure out if thats will work with my case, if you have any good reference, let me know, thanks

Comment: How would nth-child work when my case or front-end code doesnt have ordered or unordered list elements? Ive posted an image of the front-end code above

Comment: I ended up using the absolute xpath (/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[15]/span[1]) since it is a static form page with input fields that wouldnt move around. Might be an okay solution for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not best practice to use absolute xpath. Better approach is to get collection of text fields using css selector input[type='text'] and set some value.